# How to upgrade easy_install to easy_install-3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I just upgraded python to version 3.4. However, the pip wasn't installed by default for some reason. So I'm trying to install pip using the command "sudo easy_install pip." But when I typed the command, it gives me an error:

> python version 3.4.0 can't run /usr/bin/easy_install.  Try the alternative(s):
>
> /usr/bin/easy_install-2.5 (uses python 2.5)
>      /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 (uses python 2.6)
>      /usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 (uses python 2.7)
>
> Run "man python" for more information about multiple version support in
>      Mac OS X.

So, I looked through online to find out how to update easy_install to version 3.4, but I could not find any source. Does anyone know how to update the version of easy_install?

Answer (score 2):

To cut to the problem of `pip`, you can just use the `get-pip.py` script from the pip site.

Download the file: https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py

And then run `python get-pip.py`, provided your account has administrator access.

*Source*: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I just upgraded to python 3.4.2 on my Mac and running 'pip install ' wasn't working for me either.

I found this link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0439/ 
which says to use 'pip3' instead of 'pip' and this worked perfectly for me.